# Qt 5.3 QSystemTrayIcon not working correctly[Linux]

Tags: c++, linux, qt

so I wrote some Qt5 application and wanted to add a system tray icon with QSystemTrayIcon. After being done with coding I compiled and ran it and a system tray icon did not appear, so I tested around, added a line so it would display a info bubble, which it did, but in the top left corner, instead of in the system tray.

Anyway I tried Qt4.8, compiled the same code and there it worked just fine.

I'm using Arch linux with latest updates, XFCE4 as DE and Qt 5.3.0-3. I made the application with Qt Creator.

I wrote an example application which has the same behaviour.
So here's the code:

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QMenu>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon;
    QMenu *trayMenu;
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    trayMenu = new QMenu(this);
    trayMenu->addAction("Test");

    trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":/ui_conf.png"));
    trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayMenu);

    trayIcon->show();
    trayIcon->showMessage("Well...", "Here I should be I guess?");

    ui->pushButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/ui_conf.png"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

it's a regression (bug) on Qt 5.x versions. Here is the bug record for it https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31762 it's still open :(

You can try gtk code in your Qt app to create a working system tray icon/menu.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks solid to me, but it looks like there are problems with QSystemTrayIcon in certain Linux distros.  Check out this link for more info:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56459-QSystemTrayIcon-and-linux

Comment: hm yes, but the strange thing is that with Qt 4.8 it works just fine with the same code. I also read that between Qt 5.1 and 5.2 beta the bug was introduced but apparently fixed and now re-introduced again?

EDIT: if you would be so friendly, could you please compile the code on your machine with Qt 5.3 and tell me if it works and what DE and distro you use?

Comment: I actually don't have a linux box right now, sorry :(